# mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I got an error on  PHP 5.6.31 and mysql:5.7.19, I use mysqli

> mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

using this code:

```
$query = "UPDATE membres
          SET sessionid = ?
          WHERE id = ?
          AND username = ?";

// Type
$type = "iis";

if (database::query3p($requete, $sessionid, $id, $username, $type, $connection)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

query3p calls :

```
public static function query3p($requete, $par1, $par2, $par3, $type, $connection) {             
    $prepa = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($prepa, $requete);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prepa, $type, $par1, $par2, $par3);

    $reussite = mysqli_stmt_execute($prepa);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($prepa);

    // I got an error on this line :
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepa, $par1, $par2, $par3);

    $stockage = mysqli_stmt_fetch($prepa);

    mysqli_stmt_close($prepa);

    if ($reussite == true && $stockage == true) {
        return array($par1, $par2, $par3);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to put only one var or two but the code isn't working, i specified i need this line.

Comment: Indeed, `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`  is purely for selecting data - not for updating/inserting/deleting. And like ishegg said, there seems to be a typo/undefined variable too.

Comment: Thanks for your advice